# How to update the Seekbar from Service to Detail Activity

Tags: android, service, android-music-player

I started by creating three classes
   - MainActivity: Where all the songs will be present
   - DetailActivity: When user click on a song it will be redirected to this activity
   - ServiceClass: to handle all service related activity

Implementation of RecyclerView with onClickListener is done and working fine. What I did is whenever the user clicked on a song I started playing the song using service (Meaning I binded the service in MainActivity)

Now, with playing the song the user is redirected to DetailActivity where I want to show updates (seekbar) how to do it?

Because the service is bind to MainActivity I am not getting how to do it? my knowledge of services is limited. Should I bind it in DetailActivity as well?

If yes then how to update the seekbar?

I have searched stackoverflow for same kind of problem but failed to do so.

The code to pass song object when a song item is clicked is below

```
@Override
    public void passSongObject(Song song) {
        int position = songs.indexOf(song);
        musicService.setSongPosition(position);
        musicService.playSong();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicPlayer.class);
        intent.putExtra("songObject", (Serializable) song);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The object is successfully received by the DetailActivity class. But how to get Service updates should I again bind the Service class?

Comment: implement LocalBinder ... then let Service have methods for register (then call it onCreate/onStart) for getting updates and unregister(then call it in onDestroy/onStop) ... (register/unregister would take some listener(interface) as parameter and Activity should implement it) ... you may also implement "real" binder (read about AIDL)

Comment: Yes, I used the concept of LocalBinder where I successfully binded the service in MainActivity. Now my question is I want to get updates in DetailActivity, so should I bind it is DetailActivity as well?

Comment: service should have something like `registerForUpdates(UpdateListener listener)` then `interface UpdateListener { void update(SomeDataClass updateInfo); }` then `DetailActivity` should implement this interface and register self .. then from service you should call `listener.update(...)` for all registered listeners

Comment: This way we can update the seekbar. But the DetailAtivity will have Three buttons (Play, Pause and Next) so I must bind the service from the DetailActivity as well. Should will it cause a problem If I did it?

Comment: use `RemoteCallbackList` - the docs say: *"Takes care of the grunt work of maintaining a list of remote interfaces, typically for the use of performing callbacks from a Service to its clients."*

Comment: RemoteCallbackList is overkill when we don't need IPC

Comment: @Selvin its basically the same: you dont have to implement any registe/unregister stuff as `RemoteCallbackList` does it in, welll... `register()` and `unregister()` methods